# How to SUM the value of the specific rows only?

Tags: mysql, sql

Would like to get the SUM of two specific rows in a table in mysql.

```
create table people(
    id int,
    firstname varchar(50),
    money int
);

id   firstname    money
1    david        100
2    jack         200
3    bob          300
```

***Say I want the SUM of row 1(david) and row 3(bob) only. The total should be 400.***

I used this query:

```
SELECT SUM(money) 
FROM people 
WHERE id = 1 AND 3;
```

but it turned out to be **100**, and not **400** as I expected.

Answer (score 8):

Here's your query. you can use `case` and `in` to get this.

`select sum(case when id = 1 or id = 3 then money else 0 end) from people`

**or**

```
select sum(money) from people where id in (1, 3)
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer given by @Metal is the way to go:

```
SELECT SUM(money)
FROM people
WHERE id IN (1, 3);
```

I am mainly posting this to explain *why* your current query is giving you a sum of 100.  The reason is that the `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE id = 1 AND 3
```

will only ever be true when `id = 1`, i.e. for David's record.  The value `3` is evaluating to true always.  So, you simply sum David's record and get a total of 100.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `OR` to select both the rows.

```
SELECT SUM(money) 
FROM people 
WHERE id = 1 OR id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can find like this:**

```
SELECT SUM(money)
FROM people
WHERE id =1
union
SELECT SUM(money)
FROM people
WHERE id =3
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use this way.

```
    SELECT SUM(money) as Money
FROM people
WHERE id Between 1 and 3
```